# Getting a single field from HTTP Response

Tags: php, android, http, post, httpresponse

I am trying to get a single field from MySQL through php and use it in my android app.. how can i get a single field when reading response from php to android without using json?
or if there is any tutorial that can help me , I'll be grateful

here's my Code

```
public Boolean postData(String a,String b) {



                   response = null;         

                   String response = null;

                   try
                   {
                      // url = new URL("http://"+"URL"+"/new/check2.php");
                       ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                      postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("check",x));
                      postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", a));
                      postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", b));

                      response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://"+"URL"+"/new/checkedited.php",postParameters);
                    // result = response.toString();
                    result = result.replaceAll("\\s+", "");



                   }
                   catch(Exception e)
                   {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                   return true;
           }
```

PHP

```
<?php   
    $host=""; // Host name 
    $user=""; // Mysql username 
    $pswd=""; // Mysql password 
    $db="pet_home"; // Database name 
    //$tbl_name="users"; // Table name

    $conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd);
    mysql_select_db($db, $conn);
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $result=mysql_query("select * from users where username='$username' and     
     password='$password'")or die (mysql_error());
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);    
            if ($count > 0){
            echo "\n";
            echo $row['filter_st'];
            echo "\n";
            echo $row['heat_st'];
            echo "\n";
            echo $row['led_st'];            
            }else{
            echo 0;

            }       

        ?>
```

Comment: you should also read a tutorial about sanitizing database inputs.

Comment: But you need to returno those 3 values...if not, you can just make a select for that value and just echo $row['myvalue'];

Comment: That's what i'm looking for getting those values from the response each one alone

Comment: So have 3 files or functions and remove the 2 you don't need?  Honestly though you should just get all 3 and parse through it on the android side.

Answer (score 0):

Just echo the single field then, no parsers, no JSON no nothing...

for example if you want 'heat_st': (just one echo, since the echo is the response you phone gets)

```
    echo $row['heat_st'];
```

Then the response to your android app will be just that one String which is the result you wanted.( you can easily convert it to int for example in Java if you need to )

if you need multiple fields, JSON is the way to go.